# Adding a computed field to every element of an array in an AngularJS model

Tags: angularjs

I'm pulling an array of users into my AngularJS model from a JSON datasource. This data is being rendered in a table, and I'd like to create a column that is computed from two values of the existing user object, without modifying my underlying data service.

```
// My model
function UserListCtrl($scope,$http) {
$http.get('users').success(function(data) {
    $scope.users = data;
});
};
```

In my partial template, I know I can do something like this:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="for user in users">
    <td>{{user.data / user.count | number:2}}</td>
 </td>
```

But I'd rather add that field into the model, so I can use it like so:

```
<td>{{user.amplification}}</td>
```

How do I add the "amplification" field to every user in my model?

As an aside, is it possible to use the `orderBy` filter on something like this:

```
<td>{{user.data / user.count | number:2}}</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eather:

1. Just after loading user do:

   $http.get('users').success(function(data) {
       $scope.users = data;
       $scope.user.amplification() = function() { return $scope.user.data / $scope.user.count; }
   });

And use as `{{user.amplification()}}`

1. Anywhere at controller:

   $scope.$watch('user', function() {
     $scope.userAmplification = $scope.user.data / $scope.user.count;
   }, true);
   $http.get
2. Or if user.data/count do not change, do same as 1. but staticly calculate:

   $http.get('users').success(function(data) {
       $scope.users = data;
       $scope.user.amplification = $scope.user.data / $scope.user.count;
   });

And `OrderBy` could be used on any expression (uncluding result of other filter)

Comment: I've updated the question, as I see that it wasn't clear before. `$scope.users` is an array of `user` objects. I'd like to add an `amplification` field to each one of these `user` objects. I can modify my json service to do this, but I wanted to know if I could do it inside my controller instead.

Comment: @Alan, you have marked the answer as correct but I also get the undefined error you have pointed out. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need your `amplicification()` function to update when the `data` and `count` properties on your `user` update, you can do something like this in your controller:

```
$scope.users.forEach(function(user) {

    user.amplification = function() {

        return user.data / user.count;

    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a second answer as I feel it's appropriate as it's distinct from my first one.

After a little looking around, I found the method I originally posted falls over if you try to add new rows dynamically, or new elements to the array which depend on the computed value. This is because the `$scope.array.forEach()` will only run when the controller is created.

The best way to solve this problem is to create a properly defined `object` which contains the  options you want. e.g.

```
function Task(id, name, prop1, prop2) {

    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.prop1 = prop1;
    this.prop2 = prop2;

    this.computedProperty = function () {

        return this.prop1 + this.prop2;

    };  

}
```

This is far more flexible as each new object created will have the new property.

The only downside is that in your ajax success callback, you'll need to pass each of your users into your 'Users()' constructor.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to add a loop and add the property to each item in that loop. I used a property of the controller but I am sure you can use scope the way you are approaching it in the question.

```
function(result) {
    self.list = result;
    angular.forEach(self.list, function(item) {
        item.hasDate = function() {
            return this.TestDate != null;
        }.bind(item); // set this context 
    });
}
```

Then in my markup I just used it like this.

```
<div ng-repeat...>
    <div ng-show="item.hasDate()">This item has a date.</div>
</div>
```